# Letters in a string double unexpectedly

Tags: java

I'm making myself a Hangman game and basically the only problem I'm having is that the letters are doubling each time i guess a new letter. For example, if the word is "Hello World" and i guessed "l" it would print
"_ _ l l _  _ _ _ l _", right, and then if I guess "w" next, it prints "H _ _ _ l _ l _ _ _  _ _ _ _ _ _ l _ _ _" (which is hheelllloo wwoorrlldd).

My code is shown below. My thought is that it's because I have a nested `for` loop, but I wouldn't know how else I could go about doing this.

```
// This checks previous letters given through String guessedlet.

for(int spot = 0; spot < wrd[0].length(); spot++)
{
    for (int spot2 = 0; spot2 <= guessedlet.length() - 1; spot2++)
    {
        char Spot = wrd[0].charAt(spot);
        String wordletter = Character.toString(Spot);
        char Spot2 = guessedlet.charAt(spot2);
        String guessedletter = Character.toString(Spot2);
        for(int spot3 = 0; spot3 < guessedlet.length(); spot3++)
        {
            char Spot3 = guessedlet.charAt(spot3);
            String guessedletter2 = Character.toString(Spot3);
            if(letter.equals(guessedletter2))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(guessedletter.equals(wordletter))
        {
            wordletter = guessedletter;
        }
        else if(guessedletter.equals(" "))
        {
            wordletter = "";
        }
        else if(!(guessedletter.equals(wordletter)))
        {
            wordletter = "_";
        }
        out.print(wordletter + " ");
    }
}
```

Why are the letters being duplicated?

Comment: You mean, like the title where the word "when" is doubled?

Comment: Why do you have two outer loops? That's probably what is causing your problem. Just store the guessed letters in a `Set`, then loop the sentence (2 words = sentence), and print the letters that are in the `Set` (using `contains()`).

Comment: If the second guess is `w`, why is it printing `H`?

Comment: Debug and step through your code or sprinkle your code with `System.out.println`s to find out exactly when the string changes and why.

Comment: Try my answer see if it works...I tried to simplify it also.

Comment: Andreas - because String quessedlet() is the guessed letters, so w and h, so it goes through that and picks out each letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your output outside of the inner loop like this:

```
for(int spot = 0; spot < wrd[0].length(); spot++)
{
    String tempDisplay = "_";
    for (int spot2 = 0; spot2 <= guessedlet.length() - 1;      spot2++)
    {
        char Spot = wrd[0].charAt(spot);
        String wordletter = Character.toString(Spot);
        char Spot2 = guessedlet.charAt(spot2);
        String guessedletter = Character.toString(Spot2);
        for(int spot3 = 0; spot3 < guessedlet.length(); spot3++)
        {
            char Spot3 = guessedlet.charAt(spot3);
            String guessedletter2 = Character.toString(Spot3);
            if(letter.equals(guessedletter2))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(guessedletter.equalsIgnoreCase(wordletter))
        {
            tempDisplay = guessedletter;
            break;
        }
    }
    out.print(tempDisplay + " ");
}
```

You only want to output once for each character in `wrd[0]`...